# Python website get data from remote host

Tags: python, html, ssh, web, cgi

I have written a little script to try to get the remote host hostname from a html page.
the script run successfully on cli, but it don't seem to be connect to remote host and get the information when running it on a browser.
anyone can tell me what i am missing please?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import paramiko
import cgi

def ssh_connect(host,cmd):
    try:
        ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh_client.connect(hostname=host, timeout=10)
        stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command(cmd)
        output=(stdout.readlines())
        return output
        ssh_client.close()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        output="KeyboardInterrupt"
        sys.exit(0)
    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        return "authenication failed"

remote_hostname=ssh_connect('10.1.2.2','hostname' )


print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Test</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>the hostname on remote host is %s</h2>' %(host,remote_hostname)
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

Comment: Have you looked at the webserver error logs?  Are the permissions correct?

Comment: Also, the variable host is not defined outside the function.